# how to pixelate "smooth" canvas image

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm trying to make a function that will take a few pictures and make a collage type thing for a background.  I've been trying to use the HTML 5 `<canvas>` but have had no luck.  I have various images each being 16x16 pixels.  When I tried to add them to the canvas, they became very "smooth" but I need them to be pixelated.  They also appear larger than i would expect for something 16 pixels large.  I have done research on this, but no results seem to be working.  Should I keep using canvas for this or is there a better/easier way?

This is the JavaScript i used:

```
var bg = document.getElementById("background".getContext("2d");
var img1 = new Image();
var img2 = new Image();
    //etc...
img5.onload = function(){
    bg.drawImage(img1,0,0,16,16);
    bg.drawImage(img2,0,16,16,16);
        //etc...
}
img1.src="1.jpg";
img1.src="2.jpg";
    //etc...
```

P.S. Im sure this code is horribly inefficient, but i will clean it up later.

Comment: Ken Fyrstenberg wrote some nice code to pixelate an image on this Stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129644/how-to-pixelate-an-image-with-canvas-and-javascript/19129822#19129822

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably the render of a scaled canvas element.

Check for solutions here:
[Disable Interpolation when Scaling a <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615009/disable-interpolation-when-scaling-a-canvas)

Comment: I've tried this multiple times, it dosen't work, I'm using the latest version of chrome and lots of people say that it does.

Comment: Please post an demo so that we can help more.