# How do you render a video as pixelated on a web page?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I know images can be rendered as pixelated with the following CSS attribute.

image-rendering: pixelated;

Is there a way to achieve a similar effect with videos?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19129822/1693593) may help - just apply to each frame instead.

Answer (score 1):

[`image-rendering: crisp-edges`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) works for both images and `<video>` elements. Tested successfully on Firefox 89.